# about the Perron method for the Dirichlet problem

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Consider $\Omega$ an open, convex and bounded set of $R^n$. Let $g: \partial \Omega \rightarrow R$ a function. Supose that $g$ is continuous except in one point. By the convexity of $\Omega $ we can use
Perron method to construct (the Perron solution)a function $u:{U} \rightarrow R$ with

i) $\Delta u = 0 \ on \ \partial \Omega$ and $u \in C^{2}(U)$

ii)$\displaystyle\lim_{y \rightarrow x} u(y) = g(x)$ if $g$ is continuous in $x \in \partial \Omega$

My question is :

$u: {U} \rightarrow R$ is the unique function defined in $U$ that satisfies the properties above?

Someone can say to me a reference that answer my question?

Comment: Gilbarg and Trudinger do Perron; you might find more about one bad boundary point in the books by Pommerenke, there is some astonishingly intricate stuff that goes back to Caratheodory, for one complex variable.